# Responsive Tabs using Bootstrap (Get them converted into dropdown like bootstrap navigation does on small screen)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I convert bootstrap tabs to the drop down menus for smaller screens .
I want them to behave like the bootstrap navigation does for the devices 
some thing like this 
[image]

I know how to stack the tabs for small screen ..but is there any way this can be achieved ..?
I have 6 tabs that become messy when displayed on smaller screens

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">tab4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">tab5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">tab6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution, it's **SIMPLE**!

First **create two display:none classes** based on media queries exactly as I have done:
One is for your **tabs to disappear** if the screen is less than 768px the other is to have the **nav-bar disappear** if the screen is greater than 768px (your desired effect.)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.nav-disappear {display: none !important;}}    

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.tab-disappear {display: none !important;}}
```

Then let's create a second copy of your menu! We are going to use the class **nav navbar-nav** which gives us the desired *drop down effect for small devices*. Let's also wrap it in a **div** with a class of **nav-disappear** because we will only want it to display when the device is small.

```
<div class="nav-disappear">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">tab5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6">tab6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

> **EDIT: We also want to remove data-toggle="tab" from navbar-nav.**

Great! Now we need to wrap our tabs menu in another **div** with the class **tab-disappear** which will set this menu to *display:none when the device has a small screen*. We don't want tabs for our small devices!

```
<div class="tab-disappear">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">tab4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">tab5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">tab6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

> **EDIT: We can keep the data-toggle="tab" here because it is for nav-tabs.**

Using this following code we achieve the following objectives:

**Display tabs when > 768px.**

**Display drop-down when <768px.**

This is my first answer on Stackoverflow! I hope you like it! :)

Comment: Sorry mate .. but this is not working for me . Effort is appreciated :)

Comment: [copy and paste my jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/irkanu/LzqKw/) Are you editing the correct CSS file? Some Bootstrap projects pull the bootstrap.min.css file. Be sure to add the CSS from the fiddle to your css file. Test out the code I linked in the fiddle and let me know if it works in your project.